# How to fail ElasticSearch index operation if id already exists?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have multiple concurrent processes (two, to be exact) that will index to the same id. Let's say index operation `I0` is done first and is followed by index operation `I1`. There's a chance that `I1` will be indexed before `I0`. Whichever is indexed first, `I1` should take precedence during searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply an optional [`version`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-versioning) to the update that can be associated with its [`version_type`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#_version_types) to guarantee that only one is used.

Supplementing the example posted in their documentation, you can do this manually like:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1?version=1&version_type=external' -d '{
    "message" : "elasticsearch now has versioning support, double cool!"
}'
```

For a `version_type` of `external`, you get:

> only index the document if the given version is strictly higher than
>   the version of the stored document or if there is no existing
>   document. The given version will be used as the new version and will
>   be stored with the new document.

It's probably worth pointing out that the internal versioning starts at `1`.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html, versioning can be used for this purpose. Just be sure to set `I0`'s version to be less than `I1`'s version.